# Can mysql take -e option and an input SQL script from command line at the same time?

Tags: mysql, command-line

```
$ mysql -h foobar.com -u user -p salesdb -e "SET @arg='date';" < "myscript.sql"
```

did not work.  I wonder if using `-e` and `< "myscript.sql"` at the same time is allowed at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "SET @arg='date';" > input_script.sql
$ cat myscript.sql >> input_script.sql
$ mysql -h foobar.com -u user -p salesdb < input_script.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

probably won't work at the same time, but you don't need that...

```
(echo "SET @arg='date';"; cat "myscript.sql") |
  mysql -h foobar.com -u user -p salesdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Found on http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/using-mysql-in-shell-scripts/

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql dbnane<<EOFMYSQL
SELECT * from table;
EOFMYSQL
```